# Show/hide link with angular

Tags: angular

I have two links. ANd I want to show the link if portfolios.length === 0"

And the other link if portfolios.length > 0".

I try it like this:

```
<p *ngIf="portfolios.length === 0" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.dashboardUwPortfolio">
       <a>{{resources.dashboardUwPortfolio}}  </a>
       <a  [routerLink]="portfolioRoute" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.portfolioDashboardAlleLink"> {{resources.portfolioDashboardAlleLink}}</a>
 </p>
```

So this is one link:

```
[attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.dashboardUwPortfolio">
       <a>{{resources.dashboardUwPortfolio}}
```

and this is the second link:

```
<a  [routerLink]="portfolioRoute" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.portfolioDashboardAlleLink"> {{resources.portfolioDashboardAlleLink}}</a>
```

But now both links are visible.

Thank you

I have it like this:

```
 <p [routerLink]="portfolioRoute" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.dashboardUwPortfolio">
        <a *ngIf="portfolios.length === 0">{{resources.dashboardUwPortfolio}}</a>
        <a  *ngIf="portfolios.length !== 0" [routerLink]="portfolioRoute" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.portfolioDashboardAlleLink"> {{resources.portfolioDashboardAlleLink}}</a>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your structure directive needs to target what you want to hide/show.
You should also define the show condition for the other url.

```
<p [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.dashboardUwPortfolio">
       <a *ngIf="portfolios.length === 0">{{resources.dashboardUwPortfolio}}</a>
       <a  *ngIf="portfolios.length !== 0" [routerLink]="portfolioRoute" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.portfolioDashboardAlleLink"> {{resources.portfolioDashboardAlleLink}}</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Very nice but how to make the link resources.dashboardUwPortfolio clickable?

Comment: make it an `a` tag?

Comment: Yes, but where ?

Answer (score 0):

A conditional with `else` attached and an `<ng-template>` tag might be the cleanest method. You define one condition with an else like this:

```
<span *ngIf="portfolios.length === 0; else otherLink">
  {{resources.dashboardUwPortfolio}}
</span>
```

And then, you add to your template the `<ng-template>` portion with an anchor to **otherLink**.

```
<ng-template #otherLink>
  <span>
    <a [routerLink]="portfolioRoute" [attr.data-resource-key]="resourceKeys.portfolioDashboardAlleLink"> {{resources.portfolioDashboardAlleLink}}</a>
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

The former displays if the condition is true, the latter if not.